# Use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP to remove ALL the occurences of a given Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

I am already using FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP flag with success but I now have a problem for a new kind of navigation.

Here is my Navigation :

A (displaying fragment 1) -> B -> A (displaying fragment 2) -> B -> A (displaying fragment 3)

I have a button in my menu to take the user back to the home (id-est A displaying Fragment 1). When I use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, it will get rid of the last two activities and bring me to  A (displaying fragment 2). How can I go back up to A (displaying fragment 1) ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Would it be better to use activities without fragments?  That is, the views you present would simply be activities.  You may have a reason to use fragments but if you can avoid them, your problem will go away.

Comment: I have to keep the Fragments for a whole lot of reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Go back the same way you went forward:  create an intent for class A, setting FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and do startActivity on it.

Comment: It doesn't work. It stays on the current Activity, completely ignoring the previous Activities in the stack